# Android App Sales in Mainland China?

Tags: android, google-play

Since google apps do not sell in China. Only Taiwan, and hong kong.....When is google planning on selling Android apps in China?

Right now, there are dozens of Chinese companies that allow developers such as myself to sell apps, and Motorola even allows sales, however, Motorola's app store is very Big Brotherish, just like iPhone store...they refused several of my apps because they contained links from my free version to buy the paid version....

None are as easy to work with as Google.